# Populating a list in a specific way

Tags: python, list, populate

I need to populate a list with 5 positions.

```
new_list =  ___ ___ ___ ___ ___
```

I receive 2 lists and I have one default value to populate the new list.

Now start the problems:

In the good way, I receive 2 values from listA and 2 values from listB and add the default value

```
A1 A2 DEFAULT B1 B2
```

But now, if for example listA is empty I need to populate in another way:

```
DEFAULT B1 B2 B3 B4
```

the same if listB is empty.

In case listA just has 1 element, and listB another element it should be:

```
A1 DEFAULT B1
```

EDIT: the listA and listB have much more objects

Comment: What is the purpose of all of this? Maybe it could help find a solution.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard the idea of this is to make a ranking. Default User is the user i want to know ranking. listA is the users with more points than the defaultUser and listB users with less points than the defaultUser

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by recursively building the list with a and b, starting with the default user.

```
def build_list(listA,listB,default=None):
    if default is None:
        default = [DEFAULT_USER]
    if len(default) == 5 or len(listA) + len(listB) == 0:
        return default
    else:
        default = listA[:1] + default + listB[:1]
        return build_list(listA[1:],listB[1:],default)
```

This will add one element of listA to the beginning and one element of listB to the end until the length of default is 5. if either of the lists becomes empty, it will simply add nothing from that list, giving the exact behavior you wanted.

It keeps going until either all input lists are of length 0 or the default is of length 5. This method will work on lists of any length including zero, but will not preserve the ordering of the elements from list A.

Some tested examples:

```
>>> DEFAULT_USER=1000
>>> build_list([1],[2])
[1,1000,2]
>>> build_list([],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
[1000, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> build_list([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10])
[2, 1, 1000, 6, 7]
>>> build_list([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[])
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1000]
```

Comment: `default=[DEFAULT_USER]` argument should be `default=None` and then `if default is None: default = [DEFAULT_USER]`. Otherwise: https://bpaste.net/show/b676f83bb8ca

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I was actually completely unaware of this behavior. Good to know. Code is updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
new_list = [DEFAULT]

# First append listB elements from start until you reach the end
# or until you append enough elements according to the length of listA
i = 0
b_limit = min(len(listB), max(2, 4 - len(listA)))
while i < b_limit:
    new_list.append(listB[i])

# Then prepend listA elements from end until you raech the start
# or until you've got a total of 5 elements.
i = 0
a_limit = min(len(listA), 5-len(new_list))
while i < a_limit:
    new_list.insert(0, listB[-i-1])
```

Which should be "simplifiable" as:

```
new_list = listA + [DEFAULT] + listB
new_list = new_list[:(len(listA) + 1 + max(2, 4 - len(listA)))][-5:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just add your lists:

```
new_list = listA + listB
# add the default value
new_list.append(DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Is not possible, because listA and listB has more than 2 objects each one, and I have to limit the new list with 5 elements

Comment: @62009030 In that case, take just 2 elements: `listA[:2] + listB[:2]`

Comment: yeah but if listA is empty I need 4 from listB

Comment: and if listA has 1 item, and listB has 5, then how many from listB?

Comment: also, what if listB is empty?

Comment: @NandeepMali in the new list as to be always 5 items. 1 of them is always the DefaultUser. The only case list can have less than 5 is if there aren't more users. So if listA has 1 + DEFAULT USER + 3 listB = 5 positions

Comment: @62009030 You need some loginc to know how many items you should take from every list, but you asked _How to populate a list python/django_ in this is a good way to create a new list from another

Comment: @62009030 check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This will work in all cases, including if list B is less than 2 elements long while list A is 4 or greater.

```
avail_a = len(list_a)
avail_b = min(len(list_b), 2)  # assume that we are taking max 2 elements from B
num_a = min(avail_a, 4 - avail_b)  # take either all of A (if len < 2), or remainder from the total
num_b = 4 - num_a  # take (up to) remainder of total

final_list = list_a[:num_a] + [DEFAULT] + list_b[:num_b]
```

If there are at least 2 elements in lists A and B, we will take 2 from A, and 2 from B.

If there are less than 2 elements in A, `avail_a < 4 - avail_b`, so `num_a == len(list_a)`. `num_b` will get assigned the remainder of the 4 available slots. If `num_b` is larger than `len(list_b)` no error will be thrown by `list_b[num_b]`

If there are less than 2 elements in B, `num_a` will be equal to either the remaining number of slots out of the 4, or `len(list_a)`, whichever is smaller.