# Specific Sort of elements to add in new list Python/Django

Tags: python, django, sorting, populate

I have this :

```
[
[{ 'position': 1,  'user_id': 2,  'value': 4, 'points': 100}],
[{ 'position': 2,  'user_id': 6,  'value': 3, 'points': 88}],
[{ 'position': 3,  'user_id': 5,  'value': 2, 'points': 77}],
[{ 'position': 4,  'user_id': 7,  'value': 1, 'points': 66}],
[{ 'position': 5,  'user_id': 3,  'value': 1, 'points': 9}],
[{ 'position': 6,  'user_id': 11, 'value': 0,  'points': 9}],
[{ 'position': 7,  'user_id': 1,  'value': 0, 'points': 3}],
[{ 'position': 8,  'user_id': 10, 'value': 0,  'points': 3}],
[{ 'position': 9,  'user_id': 4,  'value': 0, 'points': 2}],
[{ 'position': 10,  'user_id': 8, 'value': 0,  'points': 2}]
]
```

is organized by points.
The idea is to choose the user_id and generate a new list with the selected 5 users.

***Example:***

**user_id=3:**

```
[{ 'position': 3,  'user_id': 5,  'value': 2, 'points': 77}],
[{ 'position': 4,  'user_id': 7,  'value': 1, 'points': 66}],
[{ 'position': 5,  'user_id': 3,  'value': 1, 'points': 9}],
[{ 'position': 6,  'user_id': 11, 'value': 0,  'points': 9}],
[{ 'position': 7,  'user_id': 1,  'value': 0, 'points': 3}]
```

It returns user_id 3 in the middle with 2 users hight and 2 users lower

**user_id=2**

```
[{ 'position': 1,  'user_id': 2,  'value': 4, 'points': 100}],
[{ 'position': 2,  'user_id': 6,  'value': 3, 'points': 88}],
[{ 'position': 3,  'user_id': 5,  'value': 2, 'points': 77}],
[{ 'position': 4,  'user_id': 7,  'value': 1, 'points': 66}],
[{ 'position': 5,  'user_id': 3,  'value': 1, 'points': 9}],
```

As user_id hasn't higher users it returns 4 lower users. So is always same logic.

**user_id=9:**

```
[{ 'position': 6,  'user_id': 11, 'value': 0,  'points': 9}],
[{ 'position': 7,  'user_id': 1,  'value': 0, 'points': 3}],
[{ 'position': 8,  'user_id': 10, 'value': 0,  'points': 3}],
[{ 'position': 9,  'user_id': 4,  'value': 0, 'points': 2}],
[{ 'position': 10,  'user_id': 8, 'value': 0,  'points': 2}]
```

on user_id=9 We only have 1 user lower so we add 3 higher users

If for example we just have 2 users in list, it should return that 2 users.
Main rules:
If we have 5 users or more, as to return 5 users.
if we have 4 users, as to return 4 users

How is a good way to do it?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating a list in a specific way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441568/populating-a-list-in-a-specific-way)

Comment: This is the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441568/populating-a-list-in-a-specific-way). You just reformulated it.

Comment: Yea, I had to change a bit previous code

Comment: Why didn't you edit your question rather than creating a new one?

Comment: Thought was easier to understand now, and the other answer on other would be out of context i think

Comment: The problem is the same, except the input data is slightly different.

Comment: yea, and i'm having some problems to adapt the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically only an update of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441568/populating-a-list-in-a-specific-way/38443636#38443636) to [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441568/populating-a-list-in-a-specific-way).

```
a = [
    [{ 'position': 1,  'user_id': 2,  'value': 4, 'points': 100}],
    [{ 'position': 2,  'user_id': 6,  'value': 3, 'points': 88}],
    [{ 'position': 3,  'user_id': 5,  'value': 2, 'points': 77}],
    [{ 'position': 4,  'user_id': 7,  'value': 1, 'points': 66}],
    [{ 'position': 5,  'user_id': 3,  'value': 1, 'points': 9}],
    [{ 'position': 6,  'user_id': 11, 'value': 0,  'points': 9}],
    [{ 'position': 7,  'user_id': 1,  'value': 0, 'points': 3}],
    [{ 'position': 8,  'user_id': 10, 'value': 0,  'points': 3}],
    [{ 'position': 9,  'user_id': 4,  'value': 0, 'points': 2}],
    [{ 'position': 10,  'user_id': 8, 'value': 0,  'points': 2}]
]

# Sort it if not already sorted
# a.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]['position'])

def find_index(l, user_id):
    i = 0
    while l[i][0]['user_id'] != user_id:
        i += 1
    return i

def get_subset(l, i):
    return l[:(i + 1 + max(2, 4 - i))][-5:]

get_subset(a, find_index(a, 3))
```

Comment: it has some error @Antoine. I used get_subset(a, find_index(a, 3))
and I got the user_id in last position of the new list. should be on the midlle.

Comment: Also if I choose user_id=2 , it just return 4 elements on list.

Comment: Yes, conversion error, sorry, this should be fixed.